# CSS3 - How to "restore" ::-webkit-scrollbar property to the default scroll bar

Tags: html, css, ipad

Hi I'm using the next css code to style scroll bars in Safari and Chrome. And works really great but I´m facing the next issue, I would like te restore the default value, when I view the site on my ipad. I'm using @media css for achived this but, I don't know how to restore the defaults values.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {  }



/*Scroll bar nav*/
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background:#FFF;    
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(204,204,204,0.8); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(204,204,204,0.4); 
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**UPDATE 2022**

I answered this almost 10 years ago and seems like after 2021 this solution stop working, read the solution from @Volomike, it might get you where you want to.

---

I just realized you can set all the properties in auto; and will do the trick. This is a self answer but I guess someday someone can have the same question.

```
/*Scroll bar nav*/
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: auto;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: auto; 
    -webkit-border-radius: auto;
    border-radius: auto;
    background:auto;    
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius:auto;
    border-radius:auto;
    background:auto; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:auto; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: auto; 
}
```

I don't know if exist another  method.

-- UPDATE --
Look like you can also use the `initial` and `unset` value
//reverting all the values

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    all:unset;
}
```

or apply to an specific one `{width : unset}` || `{width : initial}`

`NOTE:` Using unset will not work on *IE11*

Comment: nothing works once it has been set with a property it seems like it's completely "stuck"  with it (tested Chrome `v88`)

Comment: Sorry but I don't think your answer is right. As a simple example, try adding `*::-webkit-scrollbar:{all:unset !important} *::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:{all:unset !important}` to https://www.youtube.com stylesheets. The scrollbar will not be reverted, but instead disappear.

Comment: Niether of these solutions does the jobb. I've tried both but I'm not able to restore to the default scrollbar.

Comment: I answered this literally 10 years ago, no one complained before 2021, maybe something changed ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ who knows. But if you are dealing with this issue right now. Would be more beneficial for the community to post and update the answer after your research is finished. More than one "this doesn't work" comment, really doesn't help anybody :)

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`initial` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) or [`unset` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) for the properties you want to revert (*depending on how exactly you want to revert them*).

Both these values can be applied to all CSS properties.

**example**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: initial;
}
```

or

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: unset;
}
```

---

If you want to revert all properties of a rule then you should use the [`all` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all)

example

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    all:unset;
}
```

---

**Notice:** No IE support for any of these as of yet.
Varying levels of support for each browser (*see the linked docs for details*)

Answer (score 4):

I had trouble with this. I don't know what exactly triggers the latest Chrome to switch scrollbars on a desktop browser to overlay mode, but it was unnerving to me because it makes the page scroller look broken to an inexperienced user. The selected answer didn't seem to work in my version of Chrome on Lubuntu Linux 20.04.1, version 100.0.4896.127. So, over several hours, I painstakingly recreated the settings to Chrome's system defaults and yet something that works in both light and dark mode too. Note I'm only styling the BODY element's vertical scroller in this example, but you can adapt easily for horizontal scrollers as well as not just apply it to the BODY element.

```css
BODY::-webkit-scrollbar
{
all:unset;
}

BODY::-webkit-scrollbar-button
{
display:block;
background-color:ButtonFace;
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
height: auto;
width: initial;
background-position: center 5px;
background-size:9px 7px;
image-rendering: pixelated;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

BODY::-webkit-scrollbar-button:hover
{
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 20px rgba(128,128,128,0.5);
}

BODY::-webkit-scrollbar-button:active
{
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 20px rgba(128,128,128,0.7);
}

BODY::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:start:increment,
BODY::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:end:decrement
{
display:none;
}

BODY::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement
{
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='ButtonText'><polygon points='50,00 0,50 100,50'/></svg>");
}

BODY::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment
{
background-position: center 6px;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='ButtonText'><polygon points='0,0 100,0 50,50'/></svg>");
}

BODY::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
background-color:ButtonFace;
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 20px rgba(128,128,128,0.3);
border-left:2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
border-right:2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

BODY::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover
{
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 20px rgba(128,128,128,0.5);
}

BODY::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active
{
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 20px rgba(128,128,128,0.7);
}

BODY::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
background-color:ButtonFace;
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
```

###### Extra Notes:

- Using the ButtonFace and ButtonText colors, you can have the scrollbar react to light and dark mode. However, that doesn't give you the varying levels of light and dark you need on the control. You'd think perhaps you could use a `filter:brightness(x);` level or an `opacity:x` level to create your varying levels of light and dark on the control -- but those oddly don't work on these scrollbars. Instead, I found that that an inset `box-shadow` set on wide spread, and nothing else, with rgba colors, worked well.
- I found that setting `width:initial`, plus `height:auto`, on the button alone was enough to set the width of the scrollbar control parts.
- I got the [triangle SVGs from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66050759/105539). Note that I changed the `fill` on those to `ButtonText` in order to make it work in browser dark and light modes.
- Note that I used `rgba(128,128,128,x)` in some cases because starting from white or black with opacity created odd issues when switching light and dark modes, and so I chose the middle value with opacity to get around that.
- The `image-rendering:pixelated` was very useful because otherwise the very tiny up and down triangle SVG icon would be antialiased so much that it would look too opaque. This allowed the SVG icon to maintain its darkness on light mode, and brightness on dark mode.

I filed this issue with the Chromium browser team to see if they can give us some reliable CSS to turn off overlay scrollbars on a given element, should we need that.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1333947

**EDIT:** Recently, I found that web server cache has something to do with the Google Chrome/Chromium/Edge Chromium browsers from somewhere around version 100+ at least here around 6/17/2022. When I turn on web server cache, any sub-page on a website going back to a previous page (as a regular relative link, not as a `history.back();` call), will consistently show an overlay scrollbar instead of a fixed scrollbar. But if I force the page with an .htaccess rule that is a website cache buster, then the problem goes away and I see a scrollbar like normal.

Answer (score 2):

As commenter vsync mentioned, once you've hid the scrollbar, if you add a new css rule to show the scrollbar, it doesn't work as expected.

**Can be solved with JS**

```
let styles = document.getElementsByTagName('style');

for(let i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
    let style = styles[i];

    let rules = style.sheet.cssRules;

    for(let r = 0; r < rules.length; r++) {

        let rule = rules[r];

        if(rule.selectorText === '::-webkit-scrollbar') {
            style.sheet.deleteRule(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with cross-site style files. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63790794/get-css-rules-chrome-extension the site that's messing me up is https://tempostorm.com/