# How to reset webkit-scrollbar styles

Tags: html, css, webkit

One of my design dependencies is styling the scrollbar and I would like it reset to the browser defaults.

I have applied the following styles in an attempt to remove the styling:

1. `::-webkit-scrollbar { all: unset;}`
2. `::-webkit-scrollbar { all: initial;}`
3. `::-webkit-scrollbar { width: unset;}`
4. `::-webkit-scrollbar { width: initial;}`

All styles applied to the scrollbar (colors, pointers etc.) were reset except for the width, which is always visible, but should instead autohide on Mac OS X and be visible in Windows.

The only way I was able to get all the styles to be fully reset was to manually remove them from my dependency. I would prefer to replace the styles in the standard way, using the cascade to override the undesired styles.

What styles should I apply to fully revert `-webkit-scrollbar` styling back to the browser defaults?

The question of how to reset `-webkit-scrollbar` styles has already been asked ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060421/css3-how-to-restore-webkit-scrollbar-property-to-the-default-scroll-bar)) but the solutions recommended in the responses do not resolve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 - How to "restore" ::-webkit-scrollbar property to the default scroll bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060421/css3-how-to-restore-webkit-scrollbar-property-to-the-default-scroll-bar)

Comment: @sol | That question doesn't have a valid answer either.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you need to place it as auto for the browser to apply the default behavior of it

`::-webkit-scrollbar { width: auto; }`